# R equivalent of the convenient dev.copy2pdf but for dev.copy2svg?

Tags: r, svg

I found the very convenient dev.copy2pdf command to copy the window I am viewing into a pdf file like so:

```
plot(rnorm(1000))
dev.copy2pdf(file="myfile.pdf")
```

And my question: is there an equivalent `dev.copy2svg` for the same effect but that writes out to svg format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, `dev.copy2pdf` is a convenient wrapper around the generic `dev.copy` function. You can use this one to copy to an SVG device, like this :

```
plot(rnorm(1000))
dev.copy(svg, file="myfile.svg")
dev.off()
```